# Flask - Facebook OAuth - request.args 'function' object has no attribute 'args'

Tags: python, facebook, flask, oauth, request

I'm trying to follow the flask mega tutorial but also test my understanding and use flask-oauth instead of openID or rauth that he uses in his tutorials.

I'm trying to write the facebook oauth step, but I keep running into an error with the request. I'm quite new so it might be obvious, but I've been googling for hour and I can't find the answer!

Here's the view:

```
@app.route('/authorize/<provider>')
def oauth_authorize(provider):
    if not g.user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if provider == 'facebook':
        return facebook_auth.authorize(callback=url_for('facebook_authorized',
           next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None,
           _external=True))
```

And I'm getting the error 
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'args'
referring to the line starting next=request.args.get ... etc

Please help, it's really bugging me!

Extra info, here are my imports:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, session, url_for, 
request, g
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, 
login_required
from app import app, db, lm
from .models import User
from .oauth import *
```

Comment: st overzealous import can bite you. i dont use flask, but you can try `import flask`, then `flask.request`. If I understand correctly what you are doing, you had to define `request` at some point earlier, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like some function is shadowing the Flask `request`. You either have a `request` function in the same module or it gets imported with:

```
from .oauth import *
```

This is one of the reasons why wildcard imports are considered a bad practice.